# Problema al realizar conexión PDO con mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Recientemente se realizó una migración de Oracle a MySQL en mi trabajo, entonces al cambiar la conexión a la BD en uno de mis proyectos me lanza errores a la hora de tratar de iniciar sesión.

El código de la conexión es el siguiente:

```
class Target
{
    public static function Conectar()
    {

        try
        {

            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=10.2.3.5;port=3306;dbname=BI_TGT;charset=UTF8','bi_tgt','password');

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $conexion;

    }

}
```

El código de inicio de sesión es el siguiente:

```
require_once("conexion.php");

class Model
{
    public static function ingresoUsuarioModel($datosModel, $tabla)
    {
        $stmt = Target::Conectar()->prepare("select ba, password, nombre from $tabla where ba = :usuario");
        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datosModel['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Me arroja los siguientes errores:

> Notice : Undefined variable: conexion
> Fatal error Uncaught Error:Call to a member function prepare() on null

El problema surge es al tratar de conectar con el servidor donde está alojado mysql ya que si uso el mismo código pero con la conexión a oracle funciona perfecto, los datos de la conexión a mysql están correctos no sé qué estará pasando, no encuentro la forma de solucionar el problema, si alguno me puede echar una mano sería genial.

Comment: Tendrias que poner el `return $conexion;` dentro del bloque `try`, no fuera de él.

Comment: sigue igual, es como si no realizara la conexión al servidor, como comentaba el mismo codígo funciona para oracle y no entiendo por qué para mysql no

Comment: Te escribí una respuesta explicando el motivo del `Undefined variable`. Cuando usas `try ... catch` debes tener en cuenta lo que te digo en la respuesta. Si la conexión no ocurre es otro asunto, debes revisar las credenciales que estás pasando en `new PDO (...)`, verificando que son las correctas para ESE servidor. Ya la IP del host suena rara, ¿tu mysql está realmente en esa IP o está en localhost? [Revisa el **Ejemplo 1** del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php), observa cómo se construye el DSN.

Comment: Si mysql está en esa ip, tendré que contactar con el administrador de bd para ver qué está ocurriendo, ya que por ejemplo en navicat la conexión funciona correctamente, gracias por tu excelente respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La excelente respuesta de Cedano, me ayudó a quitar el problema con la variable indefinida, efectivamente estaba retornando mal la respuesta en mi `try`, pero seguía sin poder conectarme a la base de datos.

Entonces imprimiendo el error que capturaba $e, arrojaba lo siguiente:

> PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication
> method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Investigando un poco encontré este post: [Solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa)
El cual efectivamente me ayudó a solucionar mi problema de conexión.

Simplemente ejecuté ese comando:

```
ALTER USER 'usuario' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'contraseña';
```

Y se realizó la conexión a la base de datos sin problemas.

Answer (score 4):

[Según el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php) (las negritas son mías):

> Cuando una excepción es lanzada, **el código siguiente a la
> declaración no será ejecutado**, y PHP intentará encontrar el primer
> bloque `catch` coincidente.

Lo que está ocurriendo ahora es que esto está fallando, levantando una Exception:

```
$conexion = new PDO(...);
```

Por tanto, `$conexion` no es definida y tienes un *`Undefined variable`*. Si la  creación de la conexión no fallase, ninguna Exception sería levantada,  la variable `$conexion` se crearía y en ese caso el return puesto fuera del `try` funcionaría. Pero esto debe funcionar en ambos casos, no solamente cuando la conexión ocurre.

La forma corrrecta de escribir tu código (independientemente de que la conexión funcione o no) sería la siguiente:

```
class Target
{
    public static function Conectar()
    {

        try
        {

            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=10.2.3.5;port=3306;dbname=BI_TGT;charset=UTF8','bi_tgt','password');
            return $conexion;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
            # Aquí puedes retornar otra cosa, según el contexto
            # Por ejemplo un mensaje de error o algo
            return null;
        }           
    }

}
```

Aquí el código te retornará o la conexión válida o `null`  y en la llamada puedes (debes) verificar el estado de la conexión antes de usarla, escribiendo así un código que evite el problema de la *ingenuidad* al programar:

```
if( $pdo=Target::Conectar() ) {
    #La conexión funciona, usarla bajo el nombre de $pdo
} else {
    #No hay conexión, actual en consecuencia
}
```

El por qué no está conectado es ya otro asunto. Debes revisar la forma en que estás pasando el DSN de conexión, la cual varía según el tipo de base de datos. Debes verificar también que las credenciales (usuario, contraseña) son correctas. En el **Ejemplo 1** del [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php) te muestra cómo conectar a una base de datos MySQL (aunque algunos de esos datos podría variar, según tu contexto).